# Get element properties from JSON file and create them in jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to give elements like divs properties from JSON file which is then included in a function call but I don't know how to get these to work together.

Slightly simpler example but this explains what I'm trying to accomplish. Trying to have options include the JSON file. Struggling with this the most as it can't work asynchronously.

```
var options;
$.getJSON("documents.json", function(data) {
   options = data;
});
```

Then I create the function createBox which should get the options JSON file and only have the instructions which properties to add to the div.

```
$.fn.createBox = function(options) {
   this.width(options.width).height(options.height);
};
```

This would call the createBox function to any div and create the properties which are included in options JSON file.

```
$('#mydiv').createBox(options);
```

How do I get functionality like this?

Comment: "it can't work asynchronously" why not?

Comment: couldn't you simply call `$('#mydiv').createBox(data);` from the `$.getJSON` response callback?

Comment: @str JSON object is not recognized even if set to a global variable because it's asynchronous (to my knowledge).

Comment: @Kaddath createBox function wouldn't understand the properties coming from JSON file. Meaning this.height(options.height); would be undefined

Comment: why would it be the case? give it a try ;) (you probably are confusing your 2 "options" variables, the global and the one in `createBox `; they are not the same..)

Comment: @Santona Yes but that does not mean you cannot use it. Just put the functionality within the callback function instead of `options = data`.

Comment: @str Sorry, running really slow at the moment. Been brainstorming this for longer than I want to admit. How would fn.function work within the response?

Comment: @Kaddath if I put functionality in response callback, it says.this is undefined

Comment: if `this` is undefined it should indicate that your selector `$('#mydiv')` returns no element, the value of `this` shouldn't be influenced by where you call `$('#mydiv').createBox(data);`

Comment: @Kaddath it works now. Server was not updating the file for some reason. Original response to put $myDiv inside the callback worked. Thanks for your time and everyone else giving input.

Comment: No problem, always glad to help ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example that seems to work. I created a very simple json for this and parsed it. Then I created a function that can be called and that sets the width of the selected element to that of the json object.

```js
function JsonData(){
return new Promise(obj => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      obj(JSON.parse('{ "width":50 }'));
    }, 1000);
  });
};

(function( $ ){
   $.fn.myfunction = async function() {
      var obj = await JsonData();
      this.width(obj.width);
   }; 
})( jQuery );


$('#my_div').myfunction();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="my_div">some text to see if i can set the width</div>
```

Comment: replace your first line by `setTimeout(function(){ obj = JSON.parse('{ "width":50 }'); }, 500);` and you'll see more clearly what is the OP's problem ;)

Comment: This works but how would I get var obj to read the json file so that it's usable in $.fn.myfunction? It's necessary to be able to read the entire json file because there are tens of changing properties.

Comment: lol you're cheating if you put all the code in the timeout :D The goal of the timeout is to simulate an asynchronous response for setting the value of the `obj` variable. If all the code execute in a timeout and that the `obj` value is set synchonously inside.. it will of course still work

Comment: please google and try a little bit yourself before asking. This is literally the first google result I got when I searched 'javascrit json parse json file': https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjson_ajax . Simply use this XMLHttpRequest but create the variable myObj first outside the function so the function simply fills it up and then you can use it in your function

Comment: @Kaddath Oops I read your answer wrong I thought it said set a timeout so its more clearly for OP. So I thought you wanted a timeout so you can see the change :p. But now that I read it correct I'm not following what you are trying to say.... Could you maybe give an example of what you mean?

Comment: the OP's problem is that the global variable `options` is not set yet when the call to `$('#mydiv').createBox(options);` because `$.getJson` is asynchronous. In your first example the variable was set synchonously, so it was working. The timeout can be used to simulate an asynchronous response.

Comment: @mrdeadsven myObj is undefined outside the XML request even if it's called outside so it can't be used in the function I need.

Comment: @Kaddath ahh ok now I get it, thanks for the clarification. I'll try remaking my snippet later on and see if I can get it to work the right way.

Comment: @Kaddath I know the problem is already solved, but could you take a look at my adjustments of the snippet? I want to know if this is what you meant and if I solved it correctly :).